RANK formula gives incorrect result when values exist more than one
1) Copy the following values and paste into A1:C8 cells in excel sheet.



Header of A column
Header of B column
Header of C column




600
4
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$8,0)


1200
2
=RANK(A3,$A$2:$A$8,0)


500
5
=RANK(A4,$A$2:$A$8,0)


900
3
=RANK(A5,$A$2:$A$8,0)


500
5
=RANK(A6,$A$2:$A$8,0)


1300
1
=RANK(A7,$A$2:$A$8,0)


300
6
=RANK(A8,$A$2:$A$8,0)



2) The following picture shows that Rank formula gives wrong result

3) RANK formula gives wrong result because 500 exists in A column two times.
4) Do you know alternative formula against RANK formula?
5) Update: Desired solution is found thanks to Mayukh Bhattacharya like following.
SUMPRODUCT((A2<=$A$2:$A$8)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8;$A$2:$A$8))


Technically what it gives is the correct result: due to the number 500 appearing twice, there are two results for 5th place, which means that 6th place is skipped.  However, you appear to be after a non-standard result/answer.  300 is 7th, because there are 6 entries ahead of it.  Both 500s are 5th, because there are only 4 entries ahead of them.  (Not suggesting that you are wrong to want this result for your use-case; simply explaining why RANK gives this result, and that it is not an error.  Just, not the answer/method you were expecting.)

The formula which can help is:
[B2]=LET(src,A2:A8,u,UNIQUE(src),XLOOKUP(src,SORT(u,,-1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(u))))


UNIQUE leaves only unique sales to allow the same sales occupy a single place.
SORT sorts unique sales descending.
For every sales (src), XLOOKUP finds it in the sorted unique sales to get the corresponding place from the sequence of places (1 to 6).
LET supports to define temporary variables like 'src' and 'u' for repetitive use.
Shorter formulas!
[B2]=LET(src,A2:A8,XMATCH(src,SORT(UNIQUE(src),,-1)))

In this formula, XMATCH provides the place number without SEQUENCE generation.
The same without LET:
=XMATCH(A2:A8,SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A8),,-1))

One more formula which counts the number of unique values qreater then the left value is for each cell of B2:B8:
=SUM(--(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$8)>=A2))

Enter this formula into B2 and fill down up to B8.
Credits to @MayukhBhattacharya who has found the formula for earlier Excel versions. With a small modification:
[B2]=SUM((A2<=$A$2:$A$8)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8;$A$2:$A$8))

Enter this formula into B2 and fill down up to B8.

@rotabor has given you a simple solution. Are you looking for RANK() without skipping dupes then could try this link which I have found over the web first results. RankWithoutskip

Thanks to Mayukh Bhattacharya this problem is solved via following formula:
SUMPRODUCT((A2<=$A$2:$A$8)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8;$A$2:$A$8)) Thank you Mayukh Bhattacharya
